# PoolExhaustedException only when calling child entity with Thymeleaf

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data, thymeleaf

I am quite new to Spring and I am trying to build a simple app with some forms and views. 
When I inject my object directly in the model via `model.addAtribute("myObject", var)` everything works fine. Here is an example :
My method addProjectForm in the project controler. The user has to select a manager (user) and a company (companies):

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/add")
public String addProjectForm(Model model) {
    List<User> users = userService.getAllUsers();
    List<Company> companies = companyService.getAllCompanies();
    Project project = new Project();
    model.addAttribute("users", users);
    model.addAttribute("companies", companies);
    model.addAttribute("project", project);
    return "editProject";
}
```

Everything is then shown in a view as a form. I can refresh this page as much as I want without getting any error.

So far, nothing fancy... But, when I try to show the page of a particular project. The page shows the info of the project, his manager and his company. The controller looks like :

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/view/{id}")
public  String viewProject(@PathVariable(value = "id") String id, Model model) {
    Long projectId = Long.valueOf(id);
    Project project = projectService.getProject(projectId);
    model.addAttribute("project", project);
    return "viewProject";
}
```

So I call the projectService (the interface actually) include via:

```
@Autowired
ProjectService projectService;
```

and the method `getProject`.

```
 /**
 * Created by SebUndefined on 21/07/17.
 */
@Service("projectService")
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class ProjectServiceImpl implements ProjectService {

@Autowired
private ProjectDAO projectDAO;

@Override
public Project getProject(Long id) {
    Project project = projectDAO.getProject(id);
    return project;
}
..... Other method
```

}

If I am right, the @Transactionnal annotation will take care (in the middle of other functionalities) of the session.close() for making it available again in the pool in the DAO HibernateProjectDAO (the interface ProjectDAO actually)

```
@Repository("projectDao")
public class HibernateProjectDAO implements ProjectDAO {

@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Override
public Project getProject(Long id) {
    return (Project)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Project.class, id);
}
... Other method
```

}

For my entities, I use FetchType.LAZY for the Many to One association. For example, a project can be only in one company ==>

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
@JsonManagedReference
private Company company;
```

And then, in my template, even with this fetch option, I am able to load on demand the company name such as follow :

```
<td th:text="${project.company.name}">undefined</td>
```

Thymeleaf load it apparently by himself on demand. Then in this case, I get this error after some refresh

```
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolExhaustedException: [http-nio-8080-exec-5] Timeout: Pool empty. Unable to fetch a connection in 3 seconds, none available[size:20; busy:20; idle:0; lastwait:3000].
```

It only appear when I load an entity which was not loaded in the controller and the number of refresh allowed before the error is directly linked to the setting spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=XX.

It would be easy to put 10000000, but it would work only for aprox 10000000 request :).

From what I can tell, it looks like Thymeleaf does not close the transaction (making it available in the pool) after getting associated entity in the template...

Has anyone previously experienced this issue ? I would appreciate some help :)

Thanks in advance !

Comment: How are you handling transactions? The @Transactional annotation you showed wouldn't allow lazy loading in the view. So there must be something that is keeping the session open, which might be also the thing that doesn't close it again.

Comment: Hi Jens, thanks for your comment. For the Transactions, I am affraid that I don't do more than getting the SessionFactory in the dao
`@Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;` and then, I just do, `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`... I missed probably something I guess... If I load an entity on a Thymeleaf template (for example project), the transaction managment seems to work. But, if on this page I do `<td th:text="${project.company.name}">undefined</td>` which means I load the company of the project, then I get a `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolExhaustedException`